# Cannot launch synaptic package manager on Ubuntu 17.10, gcc:7.2.0

Tags: synaptic

I'm quite new to Ubuntu. I've installed synaptic using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

and this is the concluding line of the output:

```
 synaptic is already the newest version (0.84.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But seems the synaptic application package refuses to launch upon prompting for authentication of password.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Thanks, I just logged into Xorg now and typed: sudo apt-get install synaptic apt-xapian-index and it worked.